# How should I use wxLogFormatter to change the logging format?

Tags: c++, logging, format, wxwidgets

I need to change the output format to a log file in my wxWidgets application.
For example, now the output to the log file looks like this:

```
10:13:19: there is wxLogDebug message
```

I want to add date and logging level:

```
05:06:2022-10:13:19 [INFO] : there is wxLogDebug message
```

I know wxLogFormatter should be used, but I don't understand how exactly. 
For example, if you create the simplest application:

```
// Application Class
class MyGUI : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
private:
    // method, where I will configure logging
    void makeLOG();
};

// Frame Class
class MyGuiFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    MyGuiFrame(const wxString& title = wxString(wxT("wxApplication")));
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyGUI);


bool MyGUI::OnInit() {
    makeLOG(); // <- here I want to configure logging
    MyGuiFrame* GuiFrame = new MyGuiFrame();
    GuiFrame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

MyGuiFrame::MyGuiFrame(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800, 600)) {
    wxLogDebug(wxLOG_Warning, "there is wxLogDebug message");
    wxLogMessage(wxLOG_Warning, "there is wxLogMessage");
}
```

The class **MyGUI** has a **makeLOG()** method, in which I want to configure logging.

How should I use wxLogFormatter to change the logging format?

Comment: the docs https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_log_formatter.html is very clear- you need to derive your own class and override its `Format ()` method. BTW, according to the same page log level is displayed/logged by default. If it doesn't for you - it is a bug and needs to be reported and fixed. What version of the library do you use?

Comment: @Igor, I use wxWidgets v3.1.6.     I overridden the Format() method. Now I don't understand what it means
And then associate it with wxLog instance using its SetFormatter()

Comment: in order to use logging you need wxLog class. By default it will use the default formatter. So in order to use your own custom formatter you need to let wxLig know about it - hence the call to `SetFormatter()` is needed. Does this answer your question?

Comment: BTW, is the logging level not there?

Comment: also you may not need to override `Format` function - you could also override `FormatTimeMS()` function to get the result you want. And check if the logging level really not being logged.

Comment: @Igor, No, I still don't understand what exactly to write in my makeLOG() function. Do I need to create an object of type wxLog ? and call the SetFormatter() method?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: I have done. But what else? How to do logging after that?

Comment: check Vadim answer...

Answer (score 1):

You need to derive your custom formatter class from `wxLogFormatter`:

```cpp
class MyFormatter : public wxLogFormatter {
public:
    wxString Format(wxLogLevel level,
                    const wxString& msg,
                    const wxLogRecordInfo& info) const override {
         ... do whatever you want here ...
    }
};
```

Then you need to tell `wxLog` to use it:

```cpp
wxLog::GetActiveTarget()->SetFormatter(new MyFormatter);
```

As usual in wxWidgets API, the library takes ownership of the heap-allocated pointer, i.e. you don't need to delete the formatter.